# Extra fields in Wordpress user panel not shown

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on a plugin for wordpress and met the problem:

There has to be shown an extra field on a user info panel aka Wordpress Profile.
I suppose that the following code cut has an logical mistake. I am new to php programming and WordPress.

```
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_internal_id' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_internal_id' );

    function show_internal_id($user_id){ 

    $profileuser = get_user_to_edit($user_id);
    $global_uid = $profileuser->ID;

    $user_current = get_userdata($global_uid);
    $user_roles = $user_current->roles;

    foreach((array)$user_roles as $cur_role){
        if($cur_role=='internal_customer'){
            ?>

            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="internal_id">Internal-ID</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="internal_id" id="internal_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'internal_customer_id', true )); ?>" disabled="disabled" class="regular-text" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <?php   }
       }
    }
```

this code cut was added to a plugin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `show_internal_id($user_id)` doesn get any id as the argument. it gets the hole user object instead.

here is my problem solution:

```
function show_internal_id($user){ 

    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    foreach((array)$user_roles as $cur_role){
        if($cur_role=='internal_customer'){
            ?>

            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="internal_id">Internal-ID</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="internal_id" id="internal_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta( $user->id , 'internal_customer_id', true )); ?>" disabled="disabled" class="regular-text" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

<?php   }
    }
}
```